# SwingWorker problems

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, try-catch, event-dispatch-thread

I am attempting to make a text-based game with a GUI in java and I need to use the SwingWorker. However I don't understand any of the tutorials and It just does not make sense to me :(.

```
public void write(String msg){
    int i=0;
    while(true){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        console.setText(console.getText()+ msg.charAt(i));
        if(i==msg.length()){
            console.setText(console.getText()+ newline);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, what I am trying to do is pass a string to a method and print it out char by char however I cannot as the sleep() interupts the EDT and locks up the GUI for msg.length()*400ms :(.

If anyone has a code solution using the SwingWorker I would be thankfull :)

Comment: Why do you want to use a swingworker in a *"text-based game"*? Swingworkers are meant to be used with Swing...

Comment: The text based game still has a GUI

Comment: `while(true){` is endless loop, I saw there `break;`, but better could be to change `true` to local variable, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about a.m. issue, `JFrame`, `JTextArea` and `SwingWorker` with value from `Random`, on this forum are codes (in SSCCE form) about 35 - 50lines about the same issue

Comment: what issue you are having using the above code? what problems did you find calling this method from `SwingWorker`'s `doInBackground()`

Comment: The issues are I do not know how to do this with swingworker. Without swingworker it just locks up the gui for msg.length()*400ms

Comment: @vishal_aim I tried doing that but I do not know how to pass a string through to the doInBackground() method.

Comment: `The issues are I do not know how to do this with swingworker` there are three ways, 1) [search on this forum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+swing+swingworker), 2) [read tutorial and run code examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), 3) [waiting for miracle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this simply to get the idea of how to use swingworker with some string:

```
public void runInBackgroud(final String msg)
{
    SwingWorker<Object, Object> task = new SwingWorker<Object, Object> ( )
    {
        public Object doInBackground()
        {
            write(msg);
            return null;
        }
        public void done()
        {}
    };
    task.execute ( );
}
```

and just call this method `runInBackgroud(msg);`